# List onItemClickListener not working with

Tags: java, android, listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="10dp"
 android:paddingStart="10dp"
 android:paddingRight="10dp"
 android:paddingEnd="10dp"
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:elevation="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/major_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        android:text="Computer Science"
        android:gravity="center" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/subject_scroll"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

`This is  dropdown.xml which is the view that will be inside the listview.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/courses_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="false">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml
the listview with id couses_list with contain the dropdown.xml view

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          Log.d("ListView", "onItemClick: true");

});
```

I have tried setting the setFocusable() to false to everyview inside listview  and other method shown in precious solutions in stack overflow but nothing worked for me.What wrong am i doing here..

ListView uses MajorAdapter which extends BindableAdapter

```
public class MajorAdapter extends BindableAdapter<Major> {

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView majorName;
    private boolean isOpen = false;
    private RecyclerView subjectRecyclerView;
    Major major;
    List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();

    ViewHolder(View view){
        majorName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.major_name);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        subjectRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.subject_scroll);
        subjectRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        SubjectAdapter subjectAdapter = new SubjectAdapter(subjects);
        subjectRecyclerView.setAdapter(subjectAdapter);
        subjectRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerListDecorater(view.getContext()));

    }
    public void toggle(){
        if(this.isOpen)
            this.isOpen = false;
        else
            this.isOpen = true;
    }

    public boolean isOpen(){
        return this.isOpen;
    }
    public Model getMajor(){
        return major;
    }

    public RecyclerView getRecyclerView(){
        return this.subjectRecyclerView;
    }
}

public MajorAdapter(Context context){
    super(context);
}

@Override
public View getNewView(LayoutInflater inflater, int position, ViewGroup container) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.majors,null,false);
    view.setFocusable(false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(holder);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(Major item, int position, View view) {
    ViewHolder holder= (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    holder.major = item;
    holder.majorName.setText(item.getCourseName());
   }
}
```

here is the bindable adapter

```
public abstract class BindableAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {


private LayoutInflater inflater;

public BindableAdapter(Context context){
    super(context,0);
    setup(context);
}

private void setup(Context context){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public final View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup container){
    if(view == null){
        view = getNewView(inflater, position, container);
            if(view == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("View created cannot be null");
    }

    bindView(getItem(position), position, view);
    return view;
}


public abstract View getNewView(LayoutInflater inflater, int position, ViewGroup container);
public abstract void bindView(T item, int position, View view);

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    return getView(position, view, parent);
  }
}
```

Comment: remove android:clickable="false" from listview

Comment: and make ListView focusable android:focusable="true"

Comment: I am a little bit confused..in your first layout, you are using recyclerView....then listView....please explain...

Comment: i have removed android:clickable and added android:focusable="true" in listView  but not working...

Comment: You are saying listview and your layout shows a recyclerview. Show your recyclerview adapter.

Comment: ListView containts cardView and recyclerView to mimic dropdown

Comment: @ujjwalmainali Please post your java code also where you are binding the data in listview.